# How to include driver class and/or class path to connect to a SQL Server 2000 database in Jdeveloper?

Tags: classpath, sql-server-2000, jdeveloper

I want to connect to a database in Jdeveloper 11g but there seems to be a problem with my driver for SQL Server 2000. I have downloaded the appropriate driver (Sqljdbc4.jar) but I do not know how to include or use it in my code.

```
import java.sql.*;

class TestConnection
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
{ 
    try
{ 
  // Step 1: Load the JDBC ODBC driver 
  Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

  // Step 2: Establish the connection to the database 
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://10.1.73.180\\SQL2000;" +
       "databaseName=reportgen;user=sa;password=*****;";
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
  System.out.println("Connected.");
}
catch (Exception e)
{ 
  System.err.println("Got an exception! "); 
  System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
} 
} 
}
```

and this shows when I try to run my TestConnection.java class:

```
Got an exception!  
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
Process exited with exit code 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

Project properties->libraries and class path->add JAR.
You might also need to add this to the embedded WebLogic instance.
You can also use tools->manage libraries to add a library and then add that library to your project.